# Extract value from all objects with similar names to a table in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a bunch of R objects, all of their names starting with abund_envir_reduc . I need to extract their value in $statistic to a data frame, with the first column being the name of the object and the second its corresponding statistic value.

Object examples ($statistic class is "numeric"):

```
abund_envir_reduc_4$statistic
[1] 0.0071
abund_envir_reduc_2_6_7$statistic
[1] 0.214
abund_envir_reduc_2_2$statistic
[1] 0.056
abund_envir_reduc_7_8_6_2_5$statistic
[1] 0.522
abund_envir_reduc_1_2_3$statistic
[1] 0.2031
```

Desired output:

```
ID                            STATISTIC
abund_envir_reduc_4           0.0071
abund_envir_reduc_2_6_7       0.214
abund_envir_reduc_2_2         0.056
abund_envir_reduc_7_8_6_2_5   0.522
abund_envir_reduc_1_2_3       0.2031
```

Comment: is it possible to make a dput of your data? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `mget` and `bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "abund_envir_reduc_.+")),
       function(x){list(STATISTIC = x$statistic)}) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "ID")
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#  ID                          STATISTIC
#  <chr>                           <dbl>
#1 abund_envir_reduc_1_2_3        0.203 
#2 abund_envir_reduc_2_2          0.056 
#3 abund_envir_reduc_2_6_7        0.214 
#4 abund_envir_reduc_4            0.0071
#5 abund_envir_reduc_7_8_6_2_5    0.522
```

**Data Setup**:

```
abund_envir_reduc_4 <- abund_envir_reduc_2_6_7 <- abund_envir_reduc_2_2 <- abund_envir_reduc_7_8_6_2_5 <- abund_envir_reduc_1_2_3 <- list()
abund_envir_reduc_4$statistic <- 0.0071
abund_envir_reduc_2_6_7$statistic <- 0.214
abund_envir_reduc_2_2$statistic <- 0.056
abund_envir_reduc_7_8_6_2_5$statistic <- 0.522
abund_envir_reduc_1_2_3$statistic <- 0.2031
```

Answer (score 2):

A raw base R option:

```
objs <- mget(ls(pattern = "abund_envir_reduc_.+"))
stack(unlist(objs))

  values                                   ind
1 0.2031     abund_envir_reduc_1_2_3.statistic
2 0.0560       abund_envir_reduc_2_2.statistic
3 0.2140     abund_envir_reduc_2_6_7.statistic
4 0.0071         abund_envir_reduc_4.statistic
5 0.5220 abund_envir_reduc_7_8_6_2_5.statistic
```

Data (please provide it next time)

```
abund_envir_reduc_1_2_3     <- list(statistic = 0.2031)
abund_envir_reduc_2_2       <- list(statistic = 0.056)
abund_envir_reduc_2_6_7     <- list(statistic = 0.214)
abund_envir_reduc_4         <- list(statistic = 0.0071)
abund_envir_reduc_7_8_6_2_5 <- list(statistic = 0.522)
```